# How to stop long running loop using button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have c# application  which having 2 buttons. First having for loop which is run 10k times. and each loop code execution take 1 second to finish.

```
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
      //My running code take 1 sec for each loop
    }
```

some time i want to stop this loop/ execution on click on another button "Stop", but its not working. Please suggest me what solution.

Comment: What does "not working" entail? errors? incorrect results? Please read [ask] your question is unclear and the code provided doesn't accurately display the issue

Comment: "*but its not working*" - what exactly is not working? There are no attempts to break loop execution in code you've shown.

Comment: The long running operation is running in the same thread that handles button click. That is why you cannot press it while executing loop (thread is doing operation, has not time to respond user). You need to run operation in a different thread. It is the simplest solution

Comment: Hi @pwas, thank u for explaining the solution as i want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not good practice to run long running operations in `UI Thread` (thread where all UI events are handled - such as button click). You should run your loop in another that.

You can use `Task Parallel Library (TPL)`:

```
    private bool stopIt = false;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
                {
                    if (!stopIt)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Here is " + i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stopIt = true;
    }
```

Comment: Correct solution but do not solve the request to stop execution. _some time i want to stop this loop/ execution on click on another button_

Comment: @Max Thanks for the tip. I fixed that

Answer (score 1):

The *simplest* solution (not best) is to add `Application.DoEvents()` into the loop to process button events:

```
private bool cancel;

public void loop()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
      //My running code take 1 sec for each loop
       Application.DoEvents();
       if (cancel)
          break;
    }
}

public void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      cancel=true;
}
```

Much better and still simple solution is to employ async `Task` (the rest of the code stays the same minus `Application.DoEvents()` call):

```
private void loopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Task(loop).Start();
}
```

Beware that you should use `this.Invoke(new Action(() => { <your code> } ));` to access UI controls from the loop in this case.